# Tomcat: java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved

Tags: java, tomcat

Installed tomcat, while starting the server I am getting this error:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:469)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.27 logs.
```

Comment: is Jdk installed? Is JAVA_HOME set?

Comment: everything was set,  but it is not working with jdk 1.8 so i moved to jdk 1.7 now it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with dependencies. Please check you have the correct java version please not Tomcat 7.027 doesn't play well with java 8. Also in your dependencies ensure you have the correct version.